# pandas getattr(df, "mean") doesn't work like df.mean()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dynamic

When I use `getattr()` to dynamically access the mean of a pandas dataframe or series, it returns a Series.mean object. However, when I use `df.mean()` to access the mean, it returns a float.

Why doesn't `getattr()` return the same thing that the normal method does?

Minimal reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
print(getattr(s, "mean"))
>>> <bound method Series.mean of 
>>> 0    1.158042
>>> 1   -0.586821
>>> 2   -1.976764
>>> 3    1.722072
>>> 4    1.129570
print(s.mean())
>>> dtype: float64>
>>> 0.28921963496328584
```

I have used `dir(getattr(s, "mean"))` to attempt to get the mean value, but can't figure out which attribute, if any, will get me the float mean value.

Comment: try: `print(getattr(s, "mean")())`

Comment: The returned attribute is a callable.  So call it, by post pending a `()`

Comment: brilliant. I did not realize that `getattr` returns the method attribute unless it is appended with parentheses. I was only familiar with `getattr` usage of type attributes. If you add an answer, @SahilDahiya, I will happily accept it.

Comment: @StephenRauch, yes - probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since returned atttribute by getattr is callable, try:

```
print(getattr(s, "mean")())
```