# How to pythonically return different dataframe column calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which goes something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def my_fun(df, calc_type):
    if calc_type == 'sum':
        return df['col_name'].sum()
    elif calc_type == 'mean': 
        return df['col_name'].mean()
    elif calc_type == 'std': 
        return df['col_name'].std()

# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': np.random.normal(25, 3.5, 1000)})

# function call
my_func(df, 'sum')
```

I was wondering if there's a more elegant, one liner, way to do so.
There is `getattr` which would be great if it worked on methods. Is there something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
def my_fun(df, calc_type):
      #specify possible functions 
     if calc_type in ['sum','mean','min','max', 'std']:
         return df['col_name'].agg(calc_type)
     else:
         print ('wrong calc_type')
```

Thank you for comment @Himanshu Poddar
, if never calc_type is invalid solution is:

```
def my_fun(df, calc_type):
    return df['col_name'].agg(calc_type)
```

EDIT: If need to use `getattr` use:

```
out = getattr(s, calc_type)()
```

Comment: if OP gurantees that `calctype` will never be invalid then one liner should be `return df['col_name'].agg(calc_type)`

Comment: It looks great. Is there a method which would work for non Pandas objects?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin - Not sure if understand, can you explain more? What is `non Pandas objects` ?

Comment: Think even on user made class with a method `my_methodA` and `my_methodB`. How could you apply them?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin - So it means need custom function/ method like [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) ?

Comment: @jezrael, No, think out of the Pandas eco system. Any object which has a method. We can access the method by `object.method()`. I am asking if there an alternative way like in the case of attributes (`getttr(object, attribute)`).

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin - I understand, so need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039460/2901002) ?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin why not use this `print(getattr(s, calc_type)())`

Comment: @jezrael, Could you add another answer with what's on the link you posted?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin - added to answer.

Comment: @jezrael, thank you. I marked it and +1.